# Windows 10 updates fail to install

Tags: windows-10, updates, windows-10-upgrade

All cumulative updates & feature updates fail to install.
Windows 10 v1803 build 17134.191. I have run sfc scannow and DISM and they report no corrupt files.

Some of the error codes are `KB4480966  0x800736b3`  `KB4483234 0x800736b3` & `KB4023057  0x80070643`.

Under "turn on apps & features" .net framework 3.5 is installed showing a black box not a check mark.

These updates and more have been failing for about six months.  I need help finding a solution.

Comment: How much free disk space do you have?

Comment: Are you dual-booting this machine with Linux/UNIX per chance?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to fix things, you can try a ["repair install"](https://neosmart.net/wiki/windows-10-repair-installation/#How_Windows_10_Repair_Install_Works)

This is 'updating' your machine to the same OS, and refreshes all the files that `SFC` and `DISM` usually miss. I've fixed several weird windows bugs with this method where all else failed.

1. Create a windows 10 iso with the win 10 installation tool.
2. Mount the iso
3. Run setup.exe
4. Install as normal, **Making sure to check "Keep personal files, apps, and Windows settings"**

Comment: If feature update to 1809 is failing then it’s very likely an in-place install to 1803 will also fail

Comment: I've had success with this in the past when standard windows update has failed. Possibly because the files are already downloaded, possibly because more is changed. Normal updates don't replace all system files like this type of install does. Also this would update to 1809, if the iso is generated today.

Comment: Feature updates through the Windows update function are remarkably unreliable. A repair install or an upgrade using the an 1809 ISO will likely work.

Comment: The process to install a feature update is the same no matter if it’s done by mounting the ISO, upgrading through Windows Update, or using the Upgrade Tool and/or Media Creation Tool.  The only difference is that the Windows Update will install the update in the background and then say it’s ready while the other options will be user intiated and then install the update in the background.  Whenever I had problems with feature updates through Windows Update I always had problems using the other methods.

Comment: That isn't the only difference. A key difference is the install media being pre-downloaded, with the required disk space pre-allocated for it. Even better if it's run off external storage, meaning the install media isn't on the same disk as the one being upgraded. I understand what you're saying about the update feature, sadly it's now just anecdotal evidence from both of us

Comment: @Ramhound they're not. Just yesterday I was able to repair a broken Windows install (WU always failed) by performing a direct upgrade thru the 1809 installer exe. WU obviously did not provide the same experience.